# Log location for Tomcat when started via Homebrew

Tags: tomcat, homebrew, tomcat8

When I start tomcat@8 via Homebrew services (brew services start tomcat@8) I can't seem to find the log location. I've got CATALINA_HOME set as an environment variable, but it doesn't seem to log to CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out. Is there somewhere I need to set to see the logs?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have on mine:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.29/libexec/logs/catalina.out
```

Comment: I see the logs in catalina.2019-12-04.log but I don't see catalina.out.